# Fine Uploader loader or Spinner not showing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fine-uploader

I'm using 'fine upload' with 'uber' script now uploading is happening but spinner or upload progress bar is not working.

```
$(function() {
    $('#UploadImagesBusiness').uberuploadcropper({
        //---------------------------------------------------
        // fineuploader options..
        //---------------------------------------------------
        fineuploader: {
            //debug : true,
            request : { 
                // params: {}
                endpoint: 'image_upload_business_logo/uploadbusinessEdit.php' 
            },                      
            validation: {
                sizeLimit : 512000,
                allowedExtensions: ['jpg','jpeg','png','gif']
            }
        },
        //---------------------------------------------------
        //now the cropper options..
        //---------------------------------------------------
        jcrop: {
            aspectRatio : 1, 
            allowSelect : true, //can reselect
            allowResize : true, //can resize selection
            minSize     : [ 150, 150 ], //if you want to be able to resize, use these
            maxSize     : [ 200, 200 ],
            setSelect   : [ 0, 0, 250, 250 ] //these are the dimensions of the crop box x1,y1,x2,y2
        },
        //---------------------------------------------------
        //now the uber options..
        //---------------------------------------------------
        folder          : '../business/uploads/business-images/thumbmails/', // only used in uber, not passed to server
        cropAction      : 'image_upload_business_logo/cropbusinessEdit.php', // server side request to crop image
        onComplete      : function(e,imgs,data) { 
            $('.business-logo').remove();
            $('#businessLogo').val(imgs[0].filename);
            $('#PhotoPrevsBusiness').html('');
            var $PhotoPrevs = $('#PhotoPrevsBusiness');

            for(var i=0,l=imgs.length; i<l; i++){
                $PhotoPrevs.append('<img src="../business/uploads/business-images/thumbmails/'+ imgs[i].filename +'?d='+ (new Date()).getTime() +'" />');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

this is my script.

here where I can add spinner script I got some thing from this website 
I have pasted this script in my HTML file but even after that it is not working

http://docs.fineuploader.com/quickstart/02-setting_options.html

Comment: Thanks for the Edit APerson

Comment: It doesn't look like you're even using Fine Uploader. You'll need to provide more information that shows how Fine Uploader is being setup and imported.  Best bet is to have a look at the JavaScript console in the browser's developer tools to zero in on the issue.

Comment: I'm using uber uploader in uber they are using fine uploader :)